# No power to a branch circuit

Tags: receptacle

We lost power to a branch circuit that supplies power to a bar fridge and some lighting. There is a gfci on it as well. No breaker was tripped further I tested all breakers as good. How can this be?

Comment: Did you check the GFCI to see if it tripped?

Comment: First thing I did. Thx

Answer (score 2):

**Updated based upon comments.**

This type of failure could be attributed to any one of the following:

1. The GFCI tripped.
2. The GFCI has broken and stayed in a fault off state.
3. There is the possibility of there being multiple GFCIs in series on the circuit and one that you have not located yet has tripped.
4. Something changed in the area of the abode such as drilling holes into walls or pounding nails or driving screws that have resulted in damage to a wire in the wall.
5. Some part of this particular power circuit was wired up with poke in wire terminations on the back of the receptacle(s). One of these connections has failed.

Note that item number 5 has a pretty good chance of being the problem if you cannot account for any of items 1 to 4. Replacement of outlets with newer better quality ones and using the side screws is the much preferred method of securing the wire connections.

Comment: I think I will start with the gfci and confirm it's functionality.

Comment: Thank you I have never lived in a house that has rigid conduit to all boxs. It would appear that the whole conduit network is energized slightly like milli volts.

Comment: @alex Conduit is a huge blessing.  You are lucky.

Comment: --Or-- there is a second (or more) GFCI on the circuit.  It's very common to have multiple GFCIs improperly series wired on a circuit.  How does that happen? Usually during a real estate transaction and inspector says "there no GFCI in location (blank) and that must be GFCI.  The seller says I can fix that myself and slaps a GFCI in.  Only thing wrong, there was already a GFCI upstream on the circuit.  Now this dual GFCI's will both trip, and must be reset in the order they appear on the circuit.